# What is the error in my regex?

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to match all `href` attributes which contains a string without any url and the string is locally file path so I write this php code:

```
preg_match_all('/href="[^(http|https):\/\/](.*?)"/is',$tidyHtml,$matches);
```

This return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tatic/css/custom.css
)
```

But when T see the html source the `href` attribute is `static/css/custom.css` not `static/css/custom.css`.

Comment: Why does this regex have square brackets?

Comment: [Stop using regex for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: @Unihedron — There's a difference between writing a quick, custom regex (which doesn't work and you have to ask for help with) to pull code out of some HTML, and writing a proper HTML parser that uses regex (as that answer appears to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get rid of the square brackets. They denote a list of characters to match, not a section.

You also have to use a negative lookbehind instead of an inverted character class. See this regex which carries this match:

```
/(?<=href=")(?!https?:\/\/)(.*?)"/is
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vJ2uX7/1)!

> How to add src attribute to this regex?

You can simply use an OR statement:

```
/(?<=href="|src=")(?!https?:\/\/)(.*?)"/is
```

Here is an [UPDATED regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vJ2uX7/2)!

Comment: How to add src attribute to this regex?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm Iranian and I could not speak English well, i want to mixing /(?<=href=")(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*/is and /(?<=src=")(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*/is

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you have to use negative lookahead like this

```
/href="(?!https?:\/\/)(.*?)"/is
```

It basically checks for a string containing `href="` at any point in the string and peeks to check if the next characters are `http` with an optional `s` followed by `://`.
If this is not the case it moves the iterator forward and captures everything up to the first double quote `"`.

> How to add src attribute to this regex? –  Mokhtarabadi

This is actually quite simple by using an or-operation to check for the occurrence of `href` or `src`

```
/(?:href|src)="(?!https?:\/\/)(.*?)"/is
```

would then be the resulting regex checking for both the `href` and the `src` attribute, matching only references that have no protocol in the URL.

Comment: Well thanks, you are right, I got confused. But I don't know how to rollback to your revision, Unihedron.